# Mongo query to filter with an array specific index based on parameters

Tags: arrays, mongodb, document

I have a few documents in a mongoDB that have the following structure

[image]

In a API web application that I am developing with spring boot I have to code the following query. I can receive a voltageLevelCode to filter register that will contains this voltage level code in the array (That it is easy) but the problem is that i can also receive a voltageLevelCode and a Type, so in this case I have to filter documents that will contains this voltage level code in the array and also WITHIN this voltage level code filter the ones that contains this type (But remember, the type within the voltage level)
I have been trying to write the query but I dont know how to dynamically set the index to filter the types within this voltage level. Something like:

```
{"voltageLevel.<TheIndexByTheDefinenVoltageLevelCode>.types" : "X" }
```

Example:

```
public List<MyClassRepresenting> findByFilter(String type,String voltageLevelCode);
```

```
{$and: [{'voltageLevel.voltageLevelCode' : ?1 },{'voltageLevel.<HowTogetIndexForSelectingVoltageLevelCode>.types' : ?2}]}
```

In this case depending on the tensionLevel received the type parameter must filter according to types within this tensionLevel

Same happens to me with another query. In SQL the equivalent is the SELECT within another SELECT to select the sub registers but no idea about how to do it in mongo.

Comment: See the manual on [Query an Array](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/query-arrays/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When asking a question on stackoverflow, it's always interesting to include what you already tried.

I think what you need is a simple $elemMatch:

```
db.mycoll.find(
  { voltageLevel: { $elemMatch: { voltageLevelCode: "MT", types: "E" } } }
)
```

Comment: No because the voltageLevelCode is another parameter. I will change that with an example. I am usisng spring boot, let me edit the question

Comment: Check now the example, I think what you have show me it is what I am looking for, i am going to test it and if it work i will give you the points. Thanks!!!

Comment: Yes it was was i was looking for! thanks and sorry because of not adding an example